# Nativescript Code Signing Issue

Tags: android, keystore, nativescript

I'm trying to build a signed release apk using the Nativescript CLI. I'm following the documents located [here,](https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-android-apps#overview) but unfortunately I'm having some problems. I have generated a keystore and key following the method mentioned in the linked docs but get an issue when I attempt to run the below command using the keystore data I entered.

```
tns build android --release --key-store-path `~/Documents/Developer/keystore/linkup-release-key.keystore --key-store-password <my_password> --key-store-alias linkup_release_key --key-store
-alias-password <my_password>
```

When I run this I get `<my_password>: event not found` when trying to create and sign my release APK from the CLI? Any ideas what would cause this? My keystore password contains special characters, could that cause any issues?

Comment: I reviewed your case, however I was unable to reproduce any issue related with this CLI command for building your project in release mode. Could you verify whether you have enter correct password for `--key-store-alias` and `--key-store
-alias-password` and you have set the correct path to your `keystore`. It would help if you could give us more about your steps that you are following, while building your app.

Comment: I actually ended up finding the problem. About to post the fix now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me ended up being that my password contained a special character. Rather than trying to properly escape the special characters in the password, I went ahead and created a new one that didn't contain any and I was able to successfully sign, build and upload my project.